# Installation from ISO using "MagicISO"

Tags: boot, system-installation

I attempted to install both v14 and v15 using MagicISO on my Dell XPS laptop.  I am looking for the dual boot option.  Previous installations were not this difficult.
- the "reboot" option didn't work so I selected the last option and had a small piece of Ubuntu software installed.
- this process still did not work as it seemed it was looking for an actual CD rather than a digital mount
- I've lost interest but now upon starting the computer it continues to go to the option screen to select an operating system
- how do I remove that piece of software and get back to just starting windows
- (note) it would be my preference to be able to dual boot with Ubuntu as an option but this is just more difficult than it needs to be.
- (note) whoever answers needs to speak really slowly as I am a program manager and not a software engineer..... if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0):

3rd party tools such as MagicISO often do not create the Ubuntu installation media properly.

Use the **diskpart** tool from Windows - open command prompt as administator and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO file and copy all the content to the USB drive.

Disable hibernation and Fast startup - open command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the old version of the Windows Control Panel -> Power Settings : uncheck Fast startup.

Shutdown the machine completely - do NOT reboot the PC.

Turn on the computer and boot from the USB (entry with UEFI).

Install Ubuntu and after the reboot select Ubuntu as default in BIOS.

Now you can choose which operating system to boot from the GRUB menu.

Comment: Thank you for your response... Prior to receiving it I created a bootable USB with v14.  Unfortunately there was an error with the software and the installation did not complete (a report was sent).  Since then I installed VMWare and installed v14 with no problem.  Have also installed several other OS as well.  Thank you for your help.